# left align image and then span side by side in a table header-th

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align an image and span text side by side, but it's not happening, 
can someone give directions please?

this fiddle has a grid with 3 columns, in second column i need to display an icon first(left aligned in th) and then a text wrapped in a span just after image-side by side of image, currently it's going on bottom of th.

Comment: Close voted your question as you haven't provided relevant code

Comment: He's got a fiddle, @Mr.Alien

Comment: @d_ominic : thats not enough. he should put some piece of code here in question to get the clear picture of issue.

Comment: @d_ominic No, if fiddle link is dead later, this question won't be useful anymore, that's why when you write questions, stackoverflow warns you to post your code as well

Comment: oh understand why fiddle alone won't help for future vistors, sorry my mistake will take care in future... thanks for correction... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `img` tag:write `float:left;` and increase `width` of that `div` to `150px`

Try this one:
I have added fiddle:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E4rf9/6/)